# Crear array json desde php +mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tengo el siguiente codigo, pero no me lo muestra como un array json, como puedo modificarlo para que se sea un array tipo `array= [{"nombre":"jesus"}]` etc etc.

```
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `transacciones` WHERE `Usercorreo` = '$Username'");
    $existsql =  mysqli_affected_rows($connect);
    if ($existsql > 0) {
        $resultado = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `transacciones` WHERE `Usercorreo` = '$Username' AND tipo='$tipo'");
        while($array=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
            $response["idTrans"] = $array['idTrans'];
            //$response["ComCorreo"] = $array['ComCorreo'];
            $ComCorreo = $array['ComCorreo'];
            $response["monto"] = $array['monto'];
            $response["fecha"] = $array['fecha'];
            $response["concepto"] = $array['concepto'];
            //echo json_encode($response);
            $comrsql=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT *  FROM `comercios` WHERE `Comcorreo`='$ComCorreo'");
                        while($rowid=mysqli_fetch_array($comrsql)){
                            $response["COMERCIONOMBRE"] =$rowid['nombre'];
                            $response["COMERCIORIF"] =$rowid['rif'];
                            $response["COMERCIOLOGO"] =$rowid['logo'];
                            echo json_encode($response);
                        }
        }
    } else {
        $response["success"]=false;
        $response["error"] = "NOHAYTRANSACCIONES";
    }

    $response["success"]=true; 

    mysqli_close($connect);
```

En estos momentos el resultado lo estructura así:

```
    {
    "idTrans": "1",
    "monto": "5998.89",
    "fecha": "2017-08-15",
    "concepto": "",
    "COMERCIONOMBRE": "Fitness Universal",
    "COMERCIORIF": "402123693",
    "COMERCIOLOGO": "logo\/1.png"
}
```

pero no es como deberia mostrarme el array, que debo modificar en mi codigo tomando en cuenta que consulto dos tablas en vez de una.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener el resultado que buscas Debes crear el objeto de la siguiente manera y luego si utilizar el json_encode.

```
while($rowid=mysqli_fetch_array($comrsql)){
    $response[0] = [
        "COMERCIONOMBRE"    => $rowid['nombre'],
        "COMERCIORIF"       => $rowid['rif'],
        "COMERCIOLOGO"      => $rowid['logo']
    ]   
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Para que al volverlo Json, el te lo devuelva en el formato que lo deseas, espero te sea de utilidad y si es así no olvides dejar tu voto.

Comment: Eso con respecto a la primera tabla cuando hace el primer while, como hago con la segunda consulta?